# Mintty opens painfully slowly while on Domain

Tags: mintty

I installed Mintty fresh this morning on a new laptop that connects to a work network over a VPN.  I noticed that when I am connected to the VPN, mintty takes **ages** to open.  After some research, I found that I could start mintty with strace to see what is going on.  When i did that, I saw loads of messages about ldap lookups.  The first is my account:

```
767294  822875 [ldap_init] mintty 7860 cygthread::stub: thread 'ldap_init', id 0x5F8, stack_ptr 0x29FCCE0
4701686 5524561 [main] mintty 7860 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: <jv:*:1066912:1049089:U-<DOMAIN NAME>\jv,S-1-5-21-1669953581-1272186783-1231754661-18336:
/home/jv:/bin/bash>
```

Then I see tons of errors around this, which looks like it is looking up **every group** in my Active Directory domain:

```
385771 23061964 [main] mintty 7860 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: <NA Wireless:S-1-5-21-1669953581-1272186783-1231754661-11202:1059778:>
376274 23438238 [main] mintty 7860 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: <Marketing Kit_Read Access:S-1-5-21-1669953581-1272186783-1231754661-9486:1058062:>
21111249 50025279 [ldap_search] mintty 7860 cyg_ldap::search_s: ldap_search_sW(DC=someco,(objectSid=\01\05\00\00\00\00\00\05\15\00\00\00\5c\21\63\23\09\08\37\49\0a\25\25\6e\39\f2\2f\00)) error 0x0A
889 50026168 [main] mintty 7860 geterrno_from_win_error: windows error 234
errno 122
```

Over and over with the windows error 234 and errno 122.

I know this is domain related because I can open mintty when not connected to the VPN and it works almost immediately.

Any suggestions on what I should do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the /etc/nsswitch.conf try uncommenting the group: line and removing the db leaving just files:

group:    files

Comment: This makes it faster, but then i see the following, which i think would cause permission problems right?  

    /usr/bin/id: cannot find name for group ID 1049089